# How to set up Appium tests in Nevercode CI

Tags: react-native, continuous-integration, appium

I have React native projet. I placed "appium" folder in it for my UI test, written on Java with help of Appium. I use maven and there is "pom.xml" file in the root of "appium" folder.
These test runs correct on local machine, form IDE or by "mwn test" command.
Now I am trying to set it running on Nevercode CI platform. Building and signing android and ios builds works good. Jest test also visible. But there is no Appium test section on "Test" tab.

I used "https://developer.nevercode.io/docs/appium-tests-written-in-java" help. There is pom.xml file, there is correct driver capabilities.

I expect that there will be some section in "Test" tab with appium test. But my appium tests are not detected by Nevercode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was error on Nevercode platform.
ANd to make appium tests visible, "pom.xml" file should be located in project root. Then you can use maven multi-module structure to include pom fiiles from subfolders.

On other side, nevercode Android emulator is very unstable. In other words, in cant be used on regular basis: emulator most of time does not work or does not responding.